# tail and head command in Linux

Tags: linux, tail, head

While executing,

$ls -1rt /directory | head -n 3
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

$ls -1rt /directory | tail -n 3
file2.txt
file3.txt

Could anyone tell me how the tail and head works internally during file listing and why this difference in no.of files?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`head` lists a certain amount of lines of your file. It won’t read it integraly, just the few first lines. `tail` does exactly the same thing, but starts at the end of the file. The `-n 3` parameter is here to stop reading after 3 lines, then prints them only.

Comment: but, head -n3 displays 3 files as stated in question and tail -n3 is listing only 2 files.. Any idea y this differnce?

Comment: You combine both `stdin` and `argv`, I’m not sure it’s a good idea… Remove the pipe or the arguments you pass to both `head -n 3` and `tail -n 3`, then we’ll see.